# How (if possible) can I run Gatling test with REST request with changing parameter?

Tags: rest, random, gatling

I am writing a load test with Gatling for a REST web service. The service's endpoint receives a parameter in the path like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/palindrom/revert/{word}
```

I am not familiar with Gatling but have to make that test ASAP. I tried different solutions but do not understand how can I provide `{word}` parameter taken from the list or file.

For the moment my code is like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class MultiRequest extends Simulation {
    private val baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080"
    private val endpoint = "/api/v1/palindrom"

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .inferHtmlResources()
        .acceptHeader("*/*")
        .contentTypeHeader("application/json")
        .userAgentHeader("gatling/3.3.1")

    val fullUrl = baseUrl + endpoint + "/word"
    val scn = scenario("Revert_1")
        .exec(http("Request_1")
        .get(fullUrl)
        .check(status.is(200)))

    setUp(
        scn.inject(
            nothingFor(2),
            atOnceUsers(100),
            rampUsers(100) during (60)
        )
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

With the code above the test runs 200 requests but always with the same parameter (`word`)

I do not understand how to provide a list of 50 words to be taken randomly 200 times. Could you pleas help?

Please, understand that the service endpoint here is just an example for the question and not a real one.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the tutorials, there's exactly what you're looking for: feeders and Gatling EL:

- https://gatling.io/docs/current/quickstart
- https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial